# Want to make Label Open Website, but iOS Simulator Stuck at Start Screen

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink

I'm making an iPhone app that opens a website when a label is clicked. However, when I run my app, the iOS simulator just stays at the title screen, and doesn't move from there. When I exit the simulator, a dialog box pops up that says, "Exception encountered connecting to CoreSimulatorBridge: connection wen invalid while waiting for a reply". Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func myButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://www.mcmastermhs.com")!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Quit Xcode and Simulator.
2. In Terminal, run `killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService`.
3. Restart Xcode.

If that doesn't resolve it, restart your computer.